# add Checkbox on Action Bar on other app to select all

Tags: java, android

I was able to make a checkbox button on menu bar and tick on it to selecting all items in my own app, it is possible to make checkbox on whatsapp menu and when tick marking on it, it will select all contacts on whatsapp?

Comment: Yes, Whatsapp guys can do it.

Comment: i tried on my own app and its easy and works

Comment: i also use overlay button on whatsapp but don't know what code will place on onclick overlay btn

Comment: i find select all button for snapchat - https://github.com/bnalls33/Snapall this is what i am luking for but on whatsApp not snapchat